# How can I fit displayed video on div background?

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe, vimeo

can someone help me to fit video on website background? Video source is from Vimeo ... i use iframe where I set video as src

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/45628635?loop=1&background=1" width="100%" height="500px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My required state you can see on image
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the black bars aren't part of the video itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give iframe tag its own class, put it in the parent container, like so.

```
<div class="container">
    <iframe class="vid" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/45628635?loop=1&background=1" width="100%" height="500px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

then scale-up the video using CSS transform and give container width of 100% and height of 500px and hide the overflow.

```
.vid{
    transform: scale(2.5);
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And put overflow hidden on whatever object this "container" div going to be located in.

Answer (score 0):

That background seems to be part of the video. You could change the width to cut off the black background like in this example. `width:93%` https://jsfiddle.net/ps96r3ub/

"https://player.vimeo.com/video/45628635?loop=1&background=1" width="93%" height="500px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>

Comment: but I need video on full website width with fixed height ... for that reason I need zoom video and fill it

Comment: The area to the left and right seems to be a part of the video itself, you can either use transform: scale(1.133, 1); on the frame to stretch the video so you can't see the black background, due to a container cutting it off, Or just alter the width to cut it off as before. That gap is there on the source here https://player.vimeo.com/video/45628635?loop=1&background=1

Answer (score 0):

From *Swordys* code... Check this snippet...

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
    }
.vid{
 transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<iframe class="vid" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/45628635?loop=1&background=1" width="80%" height="500px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```

Comment: this is my actual state man ... I need remove black borders and zoom content to fit website width with fixed height